# show next working day (skip weekends and holidays) through jquery

Tags: jquery, date

I need to show next working day (skip weekends and holidays). I have script that skips weekends but I don't know how to combine it with list of holidays.

skip weekends:

```
var endDate = "", noOfDaysToAdd = 1, count = 0;
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = noOfDaysToAdd;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
endDate = new Date(someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 1));
if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6 ){
   count++;
}
}

var dd = endDate.getDate();
var mm = endDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = endDate.getFullYear();
var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;

alert(someFormattedDate);
```

and I have list with dates of holidays (contains dates with and without year)

```
var hol= 1/1,4/7,25/12,11/11,19/11/2015;
```

I need:

- if generated date is in $hol or is weekend, then skip it (note: dates can follow each other)
- It would be better if output will be in format d/m/y

Examples:

- if script generates date '06/03/2015' than show it (it is not in list and it is not sunday or saturday)
- if script generates date '11/11/2015' than return '12/11/2015' ('11/11/2015' is in array)
- if script generates date '07/03/2015' than return '09/03/2015' ('07/03/2015' is saturday)

Comment: You're going to run into problem sooner or later - some holidays move around year to year for starters. Holidays are a uniquely tricky concept, they vary from country to country, from region to region and as already mentioned move about. I maintain a huge database of holidays for my app to do exactly this. Its a royal PITA

Comment: ok. I need to exclude some dates ( they are listed in admin panel )